# Не находится System.Web.httpUtility.UrlEncode

Tags: c#

В Visual Studio C# Экспресс выпуск 2008.

Везде написано, что надо добавлять System.Web... Но это некоим образом не помогает. Также пишут, что надо выбрать .Net FrameWork 3.5, вместо .Net FrameWork Client Profile.

Что ещё попробовать?)

Answer (score 1):

Для использования метода UrlEncode необходимо добавить в References сборку System.Web, тогда данный метод будет доступен.

Comment: Каким именно образом добавить? Я указал его как using System.web; и Добавил ссылку тоже на System.Web.. Всё равно не видит этот метод..

Comment: Всё, я разобрался!)) В "Ссылки" добавил его и заработало..)

Answer (score 0):

Dot net Framework 4.5 поддерживает HttpUtility, как и в пространстве имен System.Web. Добавьте ссылку System.Web без ссылки System.Web.Extensions (Удалите ссылку на неё) в ваш проект. Если это не работает, удалите существующую и добавьте новую ссылку System.Web. Также проверьте, на какой фреймворк он нацелен, должен быть .NET Framework 4 или 4.5 без клиента.